# Ampersand (&) added to 'Group' in Column Header

Tags: c#, datagridview

For some reason whenever I give my column header the title `Group` it is being displayed as `&Group`. Is the string `Group` reserved or something? If I change the `LocalizedDisplayName` to something like `Group1` then it displays properly. All my other columns are being displayed correctly.

My code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Group
/// </summary>
[Localization.LocalizedDisplayName("Group")]
public string Group { get; set; }
```

[image: Datagridview with &]

Comment: I believe that the attribute is looking in your resources file for "Group" and finding the value "&Group" to display.

Comment: Wow you nailed it. Thanks!